# Making a pointer to std::vector of base class pointers point to std::vector of derived class pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, vector, new-operator

Apologize for the verbose title. I do not know how to express this succinctly.

```
class A 
{
      bool a1; 
      unsigned int a2 ; 
      virtual bool aFn1(unsigned int t_) = 0 ; 
      virtual void aFn2(unsigned int t_, bool val_) = 0 ;  
      A() 
      {
           a1 = false ; a2 = 0 ; 
      };
}
```

Next:

```
#include <bitset> 
#define MAX_SIZE 500 

class B : public class A 
{
  private: 
     std::bitset<MAX_SIZE> _bmem; 
  public:
     B() : A() {}; 
     using A::aFn1 ;            
     virtual bool aFn1(unsigned int t_) 
        {
           return _bemem[t_] 
        } 
      using A::aFn2;
     virtual void aFn2(unsigned int t_, bool val_)
     {
        _bemem[t_] = val_ ; 

     }
}
```

Next:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

std::vector<A*> * vecA; 
vecA = new std::vector<B*> ;
```

But this last step does not work. clang complete tells me

> assigning to `std::vector<A*> *` from incompatible type `std::vector<B*>`

But since `B` derives from `A`, this should be possible right? I have seen examples where people use

```
B bObj;
A *aObj = &bObj ;
```

So could you please tell me what mistake I am making?

The reason I go through all this, is because I have `class C` and `class D`, exactly like `class B`, where the only difference is that `#define MAX_SIZE` is different.

I do this because, I need a `bitset` of different sizes, to be used in different phases of the program. And `bitset` requires the number of elements it needs to store at compile time.

Comment: `B` derives from `A` doesn't mean `vector<B*> *` is convertible to `vector<A*> *`, those are completely unrelated types. Why do you need to store a `vector<B*> *` in `vecA`? And why on earth are you `new`ing a `vector`? `A` needs to have a `virtual` destructor, and look into `unique_ptr` since you're using C++11.

Comment: @Praetorian Could you tell me why I should not new a vector ?

Comment: @Praetorian I need to create at least a million of these objects. They are used as private member of another class. So I was thinking may be using unique_ptr will lead to performance degradation. I am careful to use RAII while using pointers.

Comment: A `vector` already dynamically allocates memory for its contents and manages that memory for you, it is extremely unlikely you need to dynamically allocate the `vector` itself. `new` is not something that should be used liberally in C++, think of it as a very specialized tool that should only be used when you know exactly what you're doing. Regarding the explanation you added, why don't you make the number of elements in the `bitset` a template parameter?

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back up this claim of performance degradation? A `unique_ptr` with the default deleter is practically the same as managing the pointers yourself, and it prevents you from shooting yourself in the foot at every turn.

Comment: @Praetorian These classes are a small portion of a large program. Changing it will take too much time. I will keep the things you said in mind, when I make the second version.

Comment: @Praetorian Thank you for the suggestion of using size of bitset at a template parameter. bitset requires a constant size at compile time. So will that work ? If it does, then I wont require inheritance.

Comment: @Praetorian Could you please answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762440/defining-the-size-of-bitset-using-a-template ? I deals with your suggestion of using a template class to set the size of bit set.

Comment: [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) takes a non-type template parameter, you need to mimic that.

Comment: For a good explanation of the issues involved in treating a `Derived*` as a `Base*`, see also the reasoning behind [this answer to "Converting `std::function<void(Derived*)>` to `std::function<void(Base*)>`"](/a/26404127/4850040), which is the same issue in a different guise.

Answer (score 3):

You are using far too many interfaces and pointers.

```
class A  {
  bool a1 = false; 
  unsigned int a2 = 0; 
  std::vector<bool> values;
  bool aFn1(unsigned int t_) const { return values[t_]; }
  void aFn2(unsigned int t_, bool val_) { values[t_] = val_; }
  void set_size(size_t i){values.resize(i);}
  A() = default;
  static A of_size(size_t i){ A r; r.set_size(i); return r; }
};
```

then use a `std::vector<A>`.

If you 100 elements of size 500, do `std::vector<A> v( 100, A::of_size(500) );`

This code will do fewer allocations, use less memory, and have less indirection than your code.  Using `new` is "code smell", often a sign you have made a mistake, unless you really need objects of extremely complex lifespan.

A `std::vector<bool> values` will be nearly as compact as a `std::bitset<500>`, and the difference is made up by the other pointers I eliminated.

Comment: Thank you. I see many interesting things here. I had used std::vector<bool> initially , but then I switched to std::bitset as it takes lesser space. I need the bits a I have more than a million items each with a bitset<500> . Also I might have to run this in embedded. Is there any performance advantage to using const ?

Comment: Could you please explain what the two last lines do ?

Comment: Does A() = default ; Tell to use the default constructor ? I did not know that. How can I learn to write CPP like you do ?

Comment: Yep, I need to use objects in a particular way , I am creating something similar to a neural network, so I needed the flexibility of passing pointers around etc.

Comment: @nnrales `std::vector<bool>` packs its elements.  It does not store 1 byte `bool`s (this is actually a problem, but in your case, it means you might as well use it).  `bitset` could store it locally, while `std::vector<bool>` has to store on the free store, but your design forces you to store it in types-as-pointers; mine lets you store `A`-as-values one level down.  That makes up for that.  The last two lines?  `A() = default` declares a default constructor for `A`; I initialized `a1` and `a2` when I declared them.  The `static A of_size` is a helper to make creating 500 element `A`s easy.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make a `std::vector<A*>*` point to a `std::vector<B*>*`, those are disparate types.

What you *can* do is push `B*` into a `std::vector<A*>`:

```
std::vector<A*> vec;
B b;
vec.push_back(&b);
```

Of course you need to be careful about the lifetime of the pointers. You might want to use `std::unique_ptr` if the vector should manage the lifetime itself.

Also note that `A` needs a virtual destructor, otherwise it is undefined behaviour to delete a `B*` through an `A*`.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this. I will have to change major parts of code to use this. I use pointer to A in other functions and changing it will be slightly non trivial .

Comment: @nnrales you can still use `A*`, that's the point. `B*` implicitly converts to `A*`.

Answer (score 2):

> clang complete tells me `assigning to std::vector<A*> * from incompatible type`...

Clang tells you the truth.

> But since B derives from A, this should be possible right?

Not right.

> I have seen examples where people use

```
B bObj;
A *aObj = &bObj ;
```

Those examples are correct. They work because `A` is a parent of `B`. A pointer of a child class can be converted to a pointer to a parent class.

> So could you please tell me what mistake I am making?

You're trying to assign a pointer to `std::vector<B*>` into a pointer to `std::vector<A*>`. `std::vector<A*>` is **not** a parent of `std::vector<B*>`. In terms of inheritance they are entirely unrelated classes. Pointer to a type cannot be converted to a pointer to an unrelated type.

Comment: So since I use A and B within the std::vector  , inheritance no longer hold ? But other wise A is a parent of B. I think I understand why this might be so , std::vector<A> will allocate space for A members, but B will not fit in that space.

Comment: I hope you understood what I am trying to do. I want a std::vector of a base class , to be replaced by std::vector of a derived class. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: @nnrales what do you mean by *to be replaced by std::vector of a derived class*?

Comment: @ I have a for loop , which goes through std::vector of A . Is there way to use std::vector of B in the for loop. Or I have a function which takes a pointer to std::vector of A , is there a way to use a pointer to std::vector of B in its place ?

Comment: @nnrales no you can't. But you can easily change your loop to go through a vector of B instead of a vector of A. The function is trickier if you want to pass other derivatives to it. If you don't need runtime polymorphism, then templates might be a more appropriate solution for you.

Comment: thanks !. Could you provide an example or pointers on how to use templates to do this ?

Comment: @nnrales can you give an example of a function to which you need to pass a vector of A? I can show you how to do it with templates.

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to

```
std::vector<Base*> *v = new std::vector<Derived*>;
```

But `std::vector<Base*>` and `std::vector<Derived*>` aren't compatible types, for the same reason that you can't use an array of `Derived*` as an array of `Base*`.

For example, in the above, what should happen if you write `v->push_back(new Base())`?  You can't have a `Base*` in your vector of `Derived*`.

For a good explanation of the issues involved in treating a `Derived*` as a `Base*`, see also the reasoning behind [this answer to "Converting `std::function<void(Derived*)>` to `std::function<void(Base*)>`"](/a/26404127/4850040), which is the same issue in a different guise.