# Defining the size of bitset using a template

Tags: c++, templates, bitset

I have a class

```
template <class MAX> 
class A 
{
   std::bitset<MAX> _mem ; 
}
```

The aim of this class , is so that I can have variable length bitsets. To be used in different parts of my program.

But clang complete gives me the error

```
template argument for non type template parameter should be an expression
```

Answer (score 6):

The `bitset` template expects a constant integral expression, not a type.  Try this:

```
template < size_t MAX >
class A { std::bitset<MAX> _mem; };
```

Comment: I was thinking an integer is a type. Retarded me.

Comment: `int` is a type.  *An* int is an object...unless it's a constant expression and then it may never become an object (an object is something in memory).

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear exactly what you want to accomplish here. When you say "variable length bitsets", you could mean a number of bitsets of different sizes, but the size of each one is constant. If that's the case, you're on the right track with `std::bitset`, but since the size of a `std::bitset` is an integer, you need to pass an integer of some sort:

```
template <size_t MAX>
class A {
    std::bitset<MAX> _mem;
};
```

If you mean you want bitsets that can actually vary in size (i.e., an individual bitset might be one size at one time, and anther size at a different time, then you might want to consider something like Boost [`dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) instead of reinventing this particular wheel.

Another possibility would be `std::vector<bool>`. This gets quite a bit of bad press (including quite a few people recommending against ever using it). It is different from `vector`s of other types, but it can still be useful as long as you understand what you're really dealing with.

One place to be especially careful is with writing generic algorithms that might deal with a `vector<T>` for any type `T`. In this case, it's fairly common that `vector<bool>` will require special treatment.

Comment: Doesn't bitset take lesser amount of space. I have more than 1 million elements  ,each having a bit set of 500. So using a std::vector<bool> was prohibitive space wise.

Comment: @nnrales: Actually, no. The exact reason people dislike `std::vector<bool>` is that it (usually now, used to be required) stores the `bool`s in a format that uses only one bit apiece, so a `vector<bool>` of 500 elements will normally be stored in something like 500/8 = 63 bytes (plus a little for book-keeping).

Comment: The OP actually makes a lot of sense, it would be nice to have answers without the judgmental bits, for example, codility and other online algorithm testing platforms don’t support boost and this is a perfect way to get dynamic `bitset`

Comment: @SkyWalker: What parts do you find judgmental? I'm a bit uncertain about what "this" you're referring to (`std::vector<bool>` perhaps?)

Comment: @Jerry Coffin the `It's not clear exactly what you want to accomplish here` bit, if you don't know or don't care then don't write an answer but when we search and find the same challenge as the OP, then the first answer we read is "I'm not so sure what you want to do " is a bit judgmental .. implying that the question is some sort of low quality BS and it's far from so.

Comment: That's not judgmental, it's a simple fact. In particular, he uses the phrase "variable length bitsets", but doesn't make clear whether he means different bitsets of different sizes (but each individually constant), or whether he means a single bit set that might change in size. That's why I pointed toward both the `bitset` based solution and things like Boost's dynamic_bitset and `std::vector<bool>`. If he wanted a bitset that could change in size, simply correcting the usage of `std::bitset` wasn't going to accomplish that. The question left two possibilities open, so I answered both.